# Не понятно откуда появляется отступ над лого

Tags: html, css

Именно на этой странице появляется отступ и не понятно почему не отображается иконка сайта, на остальных страницах такой причины не наблюдается... Не понятно откуда появляется в просмотр кода элемента код который обвёл красным маркером на скриншоте, если его удалить то отступ пропадёт. Ссылка вот: 
Я без понятия куда копать когда в самом html файле нету этого...

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Comment: Не понятно, где это лого вообще.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять кодировку файла на UTF-8 без BOM (например, с помощью Notepad++).

Answer (score 0):

Запись `&#65279` - это символь Unicode 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (`U+FEFF`). Может быть, что ваш редактор текста не знает символов этого типа - вы вероятно использовали копирование текста из другого источника.

Лучше всего удалить текст вокруг этого и написать его снова из клавиатуры.